# Each grep result to different file

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep

I have something like `grep "keyword" -B 3 log`. It shows a lot of results, like:

```
some trash
[GET] /orders/42
one more trash
keyword and useful info

[GET] /orders/43
some trash
one more trash
keyword and useful info

some trash
one more trash
[GET] /orders/44
keyword and useful info
```

How can I save each `grep` result into a separate file `42, 43, 44` with `keyword and useful info` line. Each `grep` result is guaranteed have one `[GET] /orders/[0-9]*` line.

Comment: Yes some lines between keyword and id exists (one, two or zero). But no overlap.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us an example of your input file and your desired output. We can probably give you a better solution than grep but we can't if we don't know your data.

Comment: Do you actually need those "trash" lines or do you only need the lines with `keyword`, each one saved in a file named after the value of the preceding `unique_id` ?

Comment: only line with keywords

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
awk -v keyword=keyword -F/ '/\[GET\]/ { id=$NF; next } $0 ~ keyword { print $0 > id }' log
```

Comment: Maybe you missed $ before id? `{ print $0 > id }` to `{ print $0 > $id }`

Comment: Oh no, it's ok. Sorry